Resolving an entity from a SQL query in EF Core
I have added an entity which resolves from a SQL query like this.  This entity is owned/managed by some other DbContext and I just use it as a data reference. No updates/deletes or DDL will be created from my app for this entity.
modelBuilder.Entity<ATableManagedBySomeElse>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => e.id);

    entity.ToSqlQuery("SELECT id FROM data");

    entity.Property(e => e.ContractId)
          .HasColumnName("id");
});

I have marked it as [NotMapped] declaratively as well as using fluent syntax. However, adding the migration causes the entity to be created in the migration code.
Is there another flag/command I'm supposed to use for this scenario?

You want https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-types?tabs=data-annotations#excluding-from-migrations not [NotMapped]. FYI using fluent configuration will override attributes.
